# How to find windows 10 activation Key

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-activation

Where can it be find? 
At activation panel i can only find option to change the activation key. The current key is not presented on this screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out. My windows 10 was upgraded for free from windows 8.1.
According to this Microsoft [page](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/product-key-windows-10), there is no product windows activation key on this case, only an entitlement.

Comment: Windows 10 activation is tied to your computer system (more specifically, your motherboard). So if you want to reinstall Windows 10 later, you don't actually need a key. Simply skip the part where you're asked to enter a key and Windows will activate itself once it can connect to Microsoft over the internet and activate that way.

Comment: And the old Windows 8.1 key will still work if the motherboard burns and i have move to other hardware?

Comment: The Windows 8.1 key will only work for windows 8.1. So if you reinstall on new hardware after the 1-year-free-upgrade period runs out, then you'll need a new Windows 10 license. If you reinstall Windows 8.1 within the free-upgrade period, then you can upgrade to Windows 10. Unlike earlier Windows versions, the license is now tied to a PC and not to a license key, which you can reuse.

Answer (score -1):

I used a freeware program called ProduKey to grab my W10 key. Try searching Google for it!

P.S. I heard that W10 keys do not work unless they're linked to a Microsoft account (due to Microsoft's efforts to try to get everything synced), so you may need to convert a Local account to a Microsoft account first, and register the product key with it.

Comment: What this program detected is a generic key, which cannot be used to install Windows 10, nor is it needed to activate it.

Answer (score -1):

I got mine from the free version of [Speccy](https://www.piriform.com/speccy).

It is different from your Windows 8 key so worth writing down. I emailed a copy of mine to myself in case you ever need to do a clean install in future. I expect it will be linked to your Microsoft account too.

Comment: What you got was a generic key, provided you didn't actually purchase Windows 10, so what you cannot be used to install Windows 10 since it is a generic key.